# Question about APIs with two frameworks using Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, rest, api, vue.js

I am new to coding frameworks and integrating back-end to another front-end framework. can you please explain if I used these two frameworks will it result an **RESTful api** or just an API or another type of API? I'll be honest i dont know how to use api or even restful api, so if I  combine these two frameworks will it be a RESTful api or just API only? thank you please explain briefly. and how does it makes as an api ? i know postman uses GET, POST, DELETE but im not quite sure..\

so my main question is: is Laravel with Vue.js is an api?

Comment: Since Vue.js is a **frontend framework** so it is not related to APIs however if you are using Laravel which is a backend kind of thing that will be an API. BTW RESTful APIs is just a kind of **software architecture** which can be made by any server-side language.

Comment: @Ishaan , oh so you mean the Laravel will be the server and database of Vue.js and that will make it as an api? so then laravel will be an api to vue?? am i correct? so what is rest api? i've red some definitions of it but i cant understand as long as i haven't tried it.. some people says the it is a rest api when Laravel and vue combined? pretty much like Laravel and Angular?

Comment: Yes, you can make APIs with Laravel and if you want to use the APIs you can use it from the frontend framework like vue.js

Comment: Ishaan, is it also the same if I use Laravel and Angular ? or Codeigniter and Angular? so they have the same purpose and the same use of api when combined?

Comment: Yes all of them are the same basically, you need a **server-side** technology to make APIs and can use it with Vue or others.

Comment: I think you should have to clear the concepts of APIs and then RESTful APIs before trying to make one.

Comment: @Ishaan , thanks man :) I think combining those two frameworks having back end as one framework and front end as another framework will be awsome, do you have any idea why it is used this way? I can instead use ajax or raw javascript into laravel.. but why use two frameworks??? is it more secure or what??

Comment: The frameworks are only used to reduce the code and time and increase efficiency, you can also make REST API with **core PHP** but as I say frameworks have their advantages so they are used. [This](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantage-of-using-a-framework-for-development) link might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is Laravel with Vue.js is an api?**

The answer here is "IT DEPENDS" upon the use of Laravel in this Framework relationships.
Mainly, VueJS is used for frotend while Laravel is for backend.

In order for your Laravel to become a RESTful API is that, the endpoints (the URLs) must be stand-alone and secured in its own without doing a lot of configuration or stuff by the ones who want to use it. Secured -- meaning it has a proper token mechanism to validate properly those who want to access your system / database.

A good example is:

**STEP 1**
Laravel could implement security such as Laravel Passport or using JWT Tokens

**STEP 2**
It should return or give with the proper credentials a "token" that would serve as additional security measure that you are LEGITIMATE to use our APIs

**STEP 3**
Whatever actions being done by those external parties, must be validated first, then authorize if they hold the correct token

**STEP 4**
Place all your routes inside the **"routes/api.php"** file, so all the routes will look like this **localhost:8000/api/your-route**

**STEP 5**
As for the endpoints (again, they're the right term for the "routes" if their purpose is to be RESTful

Example code:
This code snippet's goal is to delete an author

**CONTROLLER**
    public function delete($author_id){

```
        $author = Author::where('_id', $author_id)
            ->first();

        if($author && $author ->count() > 0){

            $author->delete();

            return response()->json([
                'message'   => 'Successfully deleted the Author!',
                'data'      => $author
            ], 200);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Not Found',
            ], 404);
        }
}
```

**ROUTE (routes/api.php) accessed through : localhost:8000/api/route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth'] ], function() {
    Route::delete('delete-author/{author_id}', 'AuthorController@delete');
}
```

The middleware **jwt.auth** tells here that the authenticated user must hold the proper token before using the API, even though the user has the correct credentials, but doesn't have the right token, would still be forbidden by the system

**PLEASE NOTICE THE NUMBERS AFTER RETURNING THE DATA / ERROR MESSAGES**
They are the HTTP responses to properly explain or tell the API users what is the problem or status of their request to the Backend app